# APEX Would like to validate my approach

Tags: apex, callout, list, map

I have written the following REST callout to update Club & Players custom object. Based on the API ID club information is fetched and updated, same for players as well. For players I need to check if the players are already exist, if exist I need to update the players, if not I will create new players.

To update players information :
 1. declared "newPlayer" list to store new players.
 2. declared "currentPlayersList" to get the list of all existing players for the club.
 3. declared Map exisitngPlayers to store API id as value
 4. if the player exists I updated the MAP values, if not I am adding the players to newPlayer list.

Could you please check the below code and let me know if it can be improved.

```
global class ClubRestCallout {
    WebService static String updateClubInformation(Integer clubId) {
        // Instantiate http request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        // declare club sObject variable to update club information.
        Club__c updateClubInfo = [SELECT Name, Id, National__c, Club_Colors__c, 
                                  Crest_URL__c, Founded__c, Short_Name__c, TLA__c, 
                                  Venue__c, Website__c FROM club__C WHERE Club_API_Id__c = :clubId]; 

        // declare player sobject variable to update player information.
        List<Players__c> newPlayer = new List<Players__c>();


        // declare the map to get current list of players from the club
        List<Players__c> currentPlayersList = new List<Players__c>([SELECT Name,Birth_Date__c,API_ID__c,Nationality__c,
                                                                    Club_Position__c,Role__c,Shirt_Number__c FROM Players__c 
                                                                    Where Club_Name__c = :updateClubInfo.Id]);
        // list of existing players API ID
        Map<Decimal,Players__c> exisitngPlayers = new Map<Decimal, Players__c>();

        // populating exisitng players map 
        for(Players__c p : currentPlayersList){
            exisitngPlayers.put(p.API_ID__c,p);
        }

        // Declare variables for URL & API Token
        final String ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx';
        final String BASE_URL = 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/';

        // http set methods
        request.setHeader('X-Auth-Token', ACCESS_KEY);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint(BASE_URL + clubId);

        // send request to get data
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        // parse the received information
        ClubJSON2Apex clubInfo = ClubJSON2Apex.parse(response.getBody());

        // Validate the response code and update club information
        System.debug(response.getStatusCode() == 200); {           
            // update club with fetched information.
            updateClubInfo.name = clubInfo.name;
            updateClubInfo.club_colors__c = clubInfo.clubColors;
            updateClubInfo.crest_url__c = clubInfo.crestUrl;
            updateClubInfo.founded__c = String.valueOf(clubInfo.founded);
            updateClubInfo.short_name__c = clubInfo.shortName;
            updateClubInfo.tla__c = clubInfo.tla;
            updateClubInfo.venue__c = clubInfo.venue;
            updateClubInfo.website__c = clubInfo.website;

            for(ClubJSON2Apex.Squad player : clubInfo.Squad) {

                if(exisitngPlayers.containsKey(player.id)){

                    // update exsiting playerinfo from JSON response 
                    Players__c updateExisitngPlayerInfo = exisitngPlayers.get(player.id);
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Name = player.name;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Birth_Date__c = parsedDate(player.dateOfBirth);
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Nationality__c = player.nationality;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Club_Position__c = player.position;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Role__c = player.role;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Shirt_Number__c = player.shirtNumber;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.Club_Name__c = updateClubInfo.id;
                    updateExisitngPlayerInfo.National__c = updateClubInfo.National__c;

                    // adding the updated info of exisitng players to map
                    exisitngPlayers.put(player.id,updateExisitngPlayerInfo);

                }else{
                    // create new player from JSON response
                    newPlayer.add(new Players__c(Name = player.name,
                                                 Birth_Date__c = parsedDate(player.dateOfBirth),
                                                 API_ID__c = player.id,
                                                 Nationality__c = player.nationality,
                                                 Club_Position__c = player.position,
                                                 Role__c = player.role,
                                                 Shirt_Number__c = player.shirtNumber,
                                                 Club_Name__c = updateClubInfo.id,
                                                 National__c = updateClubInfo.National__c));
                }               
            }

        }

        try
        {
            // DML statement to update club information
            update updateClubInfo;
            insert newPlayer;
            update exisitngPlayers.values();
            return 'Successful Update';
        } catch (DmlException e){
            return 'Unsuccessful Update' + e;
        }
    }

    static Date parsedDate(String dateString) {

        String year = dateString.substring(0,4);
        String month = dateString.substring(5,7);
        String day = dateString.substring(8,10);
        System.debug(Year + month + day);
        Date parsedDate = Date.parse(month + '/' + day+ '/' + year);  
        return parsedDate;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any specific issue you are facing? In its current form it seems you are asking for a code review, which is primarily opinion based. You may like to take a look at [**How to Ask**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [**edit your question**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/241447/edit) if you are facing any specific issue so that someone can help you out here.

Comment: There is also [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you're strictly looking for a review. There's not many apex questions over there, but I do keep an eye out.

Comment: Code does not have any issue, it's runs fine and as expected. I am looking for someone to review the code and see if there is a better approach in using list and map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Non-Atomic Transaction

This code, if the second or third DML operation fail, will still allow the previous actions to be saved to the database. This is usually not what you want to do, because your data may be in an invalid state.

```
try
{
    // DML statement to update club information
    update updateClubInfo;
    insert newPlayer;
    update exisitngPlayers.values();
    return 'Successful Update';
} catch (DmlException e){
    return 'Unsuccessful Update' + e;
}
```

Instead, make sure you use transaction control to rollback the changes:

```
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
...
try
{
    // DML statement to update club information
    update updateClubInfo;
    insert newPlayer;
    update exisitngPlayers.values();
    return 'Successful Update';
} catch (DmlException e){
    Database.rollback(sp);
    return 'Unsuccessful Update' + e;
}
```

## Possible Security Problem

If `ACCESS_KEY` is a live key, you should delete or deactivate it and get a new one. Never use a live access token on public forums. Also, avoiding putting these in source code anyways. They should be stored in custom metadata/custom settings and preferably encrypted.

## Date Parsing

The method `parsedDate` is not necessary. The method `Date.valueOf(string)` already specifically supports the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. In fact, your version is actually more fragile, since it depends on the user's locale. Consider using the built-in method.

---

## Minor Issues

`System.debug(response.getStatusCode() == 200); {` has an extra trailing `{` and a matching `}` later on. This adds an extra layer of indentation that doesn't need to be there.

`List<Players__c> currentPlayersList = new List<Players__c>([select...` wastes CPU time; just assign a query directly like the others (e.g. `List<Players__c> currentPlayersList = [select...`).

`exisitng` should be spelled `existing`. Taking the time to make sure there are few to typos will improve code legibility for future readers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, learned a lot. Regarding Date Parsing, I wrote parsedDate because Date format from JSON response is "1994-10-03T00:00:00Z",  could you please explain me, which built-in method I can use?

Comment: @Nandha You may be able to change your wrapper class (ClubJSON2Apex) to use Date or (more likely) DateTime instead of a String, which should provide automatic parsing during deserialization.

Comment: Thanks I modified the Wrapper class to use builtin method.